# Scala or Java Library for fixing malformed URIs

Tags: java, scala, uri, malformed

Does anyone know of a good Scala or Java library that can fix common problems in malformed URIs, such as containing characters that should be escaped but aren't?

Answer (score 3):

I've tested a few libraries, including the now legacy [URIUtil](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil.html#encodeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) of HTTPClient without feeling I found any viable solution. Typically, I've had enough success with this type of [java.net.URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) construct though:

```
/**
 * Tries to construct an url by breaking it up into its smallest elements
 * and encode each component individually using the full URI constructor:
 *
 *    foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
 *    \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
 *     |           |            |            |        |
 *  scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
 */
public URI parseUrl(String s) throws Exception {
   URL u = new URL(s);
   return new URI(
        u.getProtocol(), 
        u.getAuthority(), 
        u.getPath(),
        u.getQuery(), 
        u.getRef());
}
```

which may be used combination with the following routine. It repeatedly decodes an `URL` until the decoded string doesn't change, which can be useful against e.g., *double encoding*. Note, to keep it simple, this sample doesn't feature any failsafe etc.

```
public String urlDecode(String url, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalArgumentException {
    String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, encoding);
    return result.equals(url) ? result : urlDecode(result, encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using `java.net.URLEncoder` for percent encoding URIs. Despite the name, it is not great for encoding URLs as it does not follow the [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1) standard and instead encodes to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format ([read more here](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#Donotuse%7B%7Bjava.net.URLEncoder%7D%7Dor%7B%7Bjava.net.URLDecoder%7D%7DforwholeURLs))

For encoding URIs in Scala I would recommend the [Uri](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/Uri.scala) class from spray-http. [scala-uri](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri) is an alternative (disclaimer: I'm the author).